# CheckBox unhide on GridView

Tags: android

I did set my Checkbox Visibility to "Gone" , in my xml file , and I want to unhide it when I go for OnItemLongListnere , on my GridView , with other words , if I have 8 pics in my gridView , I want to unhide this CheckBox for each photo! Thanks

My GridViewAdapter

```
 public class GridViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
// Declare variables
ImageView image;
private Activity activity;
private String[] filepath;
private String[] filename;

private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;

public GridViewAdapter(Activity a, String[] fpath, String[] fname) {
    activity = a;
    filepath = fpath;
    filename = fname;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

}


public int getCount() {
    return filepath.length;

}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}


public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View vi = convertView;
    if (convertView == null)
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.gridview_item, null);
    // Locate the TextView in gridview_item.xml
    TextView text = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.text);
    // Locate the ImageView in gridview_item.xml
     image = (ImageView) vi.findViewById(R.id.grid_image);

    // Set file name to the TextView followed by the position
    File file = new File(filepath[position]);
    Picasso.with(activity).load(file).placeholder(R.drawable.rtrt).fit().centerCrop().into(image);


    // Decode the filepath with BitmapFactory followed by the position


    // Set the decoded bitmap into ImageView
  //  image.setImageBitmap(bmp);
    return vi;
}
```

}

Comment: post your adapter for grid view

Comment: i need your `R.layout.gridview_item` xml code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this can help you.

```
public class GridViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        // Declare variables

        private Activity activity;
        private String[] filepath;
        private String[] filename;

        private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;

        public GridViewAdapter(Activity a, String[] fpath, String[] fname) {
            activity = a;
            filepath = fpath;
            filename = fname;
            inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        }

        public int getCount() {
            return filepath.length;
        }

        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            final Holder holder;

            if (convertView == null) {
                holder = new Holder();
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.gridview_item, null);
                holder.image = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.grid_image);
                holder.text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text);
                holder.ck = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkbox);
                convertView.setTag(holder);
            } else {
                holder = (Holder) convertView.getTag();
            }

            // Set file name to the TextView followed by the position
            File file = new File(filepath[position]);
            holder.ck.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            Picasso.with(activity).load(file).placeholder(R.drawable.rtrt).fit().centerCrop().into(holder.image);
            return convertView;
        }

        class Holder {
            ImageView image;
            TextView text;
            CheckBox ck;
        }
    }
```

and on GridView LongClick

```
gridview.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {

    public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
            int position, long arg3) {
        CheckBox ck = (CheckBox)arg1.findViewById(R.id.checkbox);
        ck.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        return true;
    }
});
```

Comment: This is awsome , but if I don't use onLongItemClickListner and I use" public void onItemCheckedStateChanged(android.view.ActionMode mode, int position, long id, boolean checked)  " what can I do ?

Comment: you want to hide or unhide the checkbox on long press of grid view item

Comment: ok , I want to unhide the checkbox , but if I want to change the color of the selected imageview , on longClickeditem ?

Comment: `OnItemLongClickListener` add `arg1.setBackground()`

Comment: hei @Deepak Goyal , I have one more question for you . If I want after I keep longItemClick on one item to unlock all the items from my gridView to be checked , thank you

Comment: i think you provide a separate option for that to unlock all items.

Comment: And how can I do it ? :)

Comment: provide a option menu item and on click that option menu refresh the gridview

Answer (score 0):

get the checkbox reference from your gridview_item layout in adapter and set its visibility View.VISIBLE.
Set onlongclicklistener on parent layout of your  gridview_item layout.